# Is it ok to put elements like <h3> inside <form> tags?

Tags: html

Is it ok to put `<h3>` inside `<form>` like below ?

```
<form>
  <h3>Business Information</h3>
  <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="TypeOfEntity" class="form-font">Type of Entity</label><br>
                    <select class="form-control" id="TypeOfEntity">
                      <option selected disabled >Select</option>
                      <option>A</option>
                      <option>B</option>
                      <option>C</option>
                      <option>D</option>
                    </select>                
                  </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-2">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="NoOfDirection" class="form-font">No of Direction</label><br>
                    <select class="form-control" id="NoOfDirection">
                      <option selected disabled >Select</option>
                      <option>A</option>
                      <option>B</option>
                      <option>C</option>
                      <option>D</option>
                    </select> 
                  </div>                  
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="EntityName" class="form-font">Entity Name</label><br>
                    <input class="form-control" id="EntityName" placeholder="Select">
                  </div>                   
                </div>                                
              </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Nothing is wrong with that. it's your choice.

Comment: You seems to miss one </div> on the bottom if you got error of thsi html

Comment: Is there any question apart from opinion ?

Comment: yea no problem.

Comment: @user2486 - This is not a mather of opinion. You have valid html or you don't. Arun Kumar Kandasamy is asking if that is the case when using a <h3> tag in a <form>. It is by the way.

Comment: You can always check your markup with [W3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can allways check validation on [validator.w3.org](https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input+with_options)
[image]

In my opinion you can put it inside or outside of the form tag.
Depending on how reusable your component will be.
If you use same form in multiple places but you want to change the title than put it outside the form. Else you can leave it inside the form tag.